# How do I stop the "[A" showing sometimes when I press the up arrow key?

Tags: bash, keyboard

I use bash and the up arrow key sometimes to be able to quickly get the previous commands I used. What is irritating is ***sometimes*** when I do this I get a `[A` instead of a previous command. After doing some research online it looks like this is a key code representing the up arrow key being sent to the computer.

I can't seem to find any answers to this online. How can I stop this from happening in the future?

Comment: Why down vote this? The suggested similar question does not answer my question. I am able to configure the up-arrow perfectly fine. What I am encountering is periodically when I use the up-arrow it produces an unwanted `[A`.

Comment: Does your arrow key produce this on the Bash prompt itself, or while another program is running? If you e.g. run `sleep 3` and then press Up Arrow, you'll get `^[[A`, which will get to Bash as the arrow escape sequence after 3 seconds, and Bash will interpret it as a command to show previous command-line, (i.e. `sleep 3`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Background**

The sequence is actually <kbd>Escape</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, and it's part of a set that was adopted by [Ecma](http://www.ecma-international.org/) in 1976 as standard [ECMA-48](https://ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-48/), being supported by ANSI as a separate but almost identical standard for a number of years (later withdrawn) and also ratified by [ISO/IEC 6429](https://www.iso.org/standard/12782.html) on the way. The upshot of this multiple standardisation is that although they are frequently referenced as ANSI escape codes they should properly be called ECMA-48 control functions<sup>*</sup>.

**Explanation**

The usual reason for seeing `[A` on the screen instead of the action will be that the inital Escape code has been absorbed unexpectedly. I cannot reproduce this on my keyboard unless I first press <kbd>Ctrl V</kbd>, which tells the terminal line driver to process the next character as a literal.

So, we can then get this sequence <kbd>Ctrl V</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, producing the visible output `[A`.

You'll notice that if you press the sequence of characters <kbd>Escape</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> in quick succession the cursor will indeed go upwards. However, if you pause after the first character you'll fail to get a cursor movement, and this is because the Escape character has a timeout associated with it. On slow serial lines to UNIX systems this used to be a real problem, and the closest equivalent is a slow or intermittent network connection, with a brief lag during this sequence transmission.

**Prevention**

Now to your question, how to prevent this. There isn't much you can do if you're on an intermittent network connection, except maybe use one of the alternate sequences such as <kbd>Escape</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>...<kbd>k</kbd>...<kbd>k</kbd> that are available during command editing in "vi mode" (`set -o vi`).

---

<sup>* Much like JavaScript should be called ECMAScript, I suppose</sup>

Comment: Is this key processing timeout the actual reason why for example `less` on long files will cause this behavior if you try to go to the end of the file with END key, while the file is also being displayed on screen?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but since End is also an Escape sequence it's quite possible, yes. I prossibly should have said in my answer that at the C programming level the timeout can be adjusted, but I know nothing that can change it from the shell (specifically, it doesn't seem to be a feature of `stty`).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @roaima, this used to be a well-known problem, seen frequently in programs running over a network or serial line where transmission delays interfere with programs (such as vi) attempting to distinguish a plain *escape* character from an *escape sequence*.  Since most users don't run programs on time-shared servers any more, they don't notice this.

The problem is that the program has to delay a "short" time to allow it to see if an *escape* character is followed by other characters which **could** be part of one of the *escape sequences* it is waiting for.  Conventionally, special keys (such as cursor-keys, function keys, etc), are sent as escape sequences.

If you happen to hold a key down, so that the key-repeat feature starts, then it's possible to send those escape sequences faster than (some) programs may read them.  When that happens, the time between individual characters tends to increase — and eventually exceed the "short" time allocated to distinguishing the *escape* character versus an *escape sequence*.

readline (part of/bundled with) bash attempts to distinguish different sequences of characters, which (like vi) may begin in the same way.  It has a feature which can change that "short" time:

> [8.3.1 *Readline Init File Syntax*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Init-File-Syntax)
>
> **`keyseq-timeout`**
>
> Specifies the duration Readline will wait for a character when reading an ambiguous key sequence (one that can form a complete key sequence using the input read so far, or can take additional input to complete a longer key sequence). If no input is received within the timeout, Readline will use the shorter but complete key sequence. Readline uses this value to determine whether or not input is available on the current input source (rl_instream by default). The value is specified in milliseconds, so a value of 1000 means that Readline will wait one second for additional input. If this variable is set to a value less than or equal to zero, or to a non-numeric value, Readline will wait until another key is pressed to decide which key sequence to complete. The default value is 500.

That is, you could put this in your `~/.inputrc` file:

```
set keyseq-timeout 0
```

and readline would wait indefinitely for those cursor-keys.  The drawback is that it can produce unexpected results when you happen to type some characters which combine to match something in its repertoire.

Answer (score 1):

In my terminal shell (Konsole using bash) I am able to reproduce `^[[A` with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> as mentioned in the accepted answer.  However, unlike the accepted answer I **could** reproduce `[A` by itself like the question specifically asks by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>ArrowUp</kbd>

When you unintentionally press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, you can press it again to stop it from escaping the first part of the arrow keypress, thereby preventing `[A` from appearing.

Comment: Which terminal were you using?

Comment: Edited answer to include that info. (Konsole)

Comment: I don't think this is correct. At least, it might work, but not for the reason given. Try `bind '"\e\e\e[A": complete'` and you can use Esc-Esc-ArrowUp like Tab for completion. And there are few keybindings (at least on Arch Linux) which start with a double Esc (e.g, Esc-ArrowRight/Left to move a word to the right or left), so my guess is that readline sees the first two Escs, waits to see if the next characters match the existing bindings, but when it doesn't, it discards and processes those characters like usual.

Answer (score 0):

All very good answers. The quick and dirty is to use h,j,k,l as your arrow keys. Or install the the full vim package. The Ubuntu distro, if I remember correctly defaults to vim??-runtime, if you just install vim?? then the problem "fixes" itself. ?? is whatever the latest full package version. On Ubuntu `apt-cache search vim` will tell tell you.

<kbd>h</kbd> = left, <kbd>j</kbd> = down, <kbd>k</kbd> = up, <kbd>l</kbd> = right